# Cost in time for constructing and running an NFA vs DFA for a given regex

Tags: compiler-construction, theory, compiler-theory, fsm, nfa

I'm going through past exams and keep coming across questions that I can't find an answer for in textbooks or on google, so any help would be much appreciated.

The question I'm having problems with at the moment is as follows:

> Given a regular expression (a|bb)*, derive an estimate of the cost in time for 
>   converting it to a corresponding NFA and a DFA. Your answer should refer to
>   the size of the regular expression.

A similar question from another year is:

> Given that, for the above example, you know the size of the original regular
>   expression, |r| and the size of the input string |x|, explain how you would calculate the cost in time for constructing and running the NFA versus constructing
>   and running an equivalent DFA.

The resulting NFA for (a|bb)* has 9 states, while the DFA has 4. Even knowing this, I have no idea how to approach the question.

Comment: You might have better success asking at the [Computer Science site](http://cs.stackexchange.com/)